# How to include external code/library javascript on wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to use a external JS library on wordpress, how I should add it to my wordpress libraries. The library is viewerjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

> Enqueue the script or style using wp_enqueue_script() or
>   wp_enqueue_style()

Example:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use enqueue styles code

```
<?php
function add_theme_codes() {
   wp_enqueue_style( ‘style’, ‘your external file url goes here’, ‘all’);
}
add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, ‘add_theme_codes’ );
?>
```

make sure that you have included `wp_head` tag in head tag